# Pull data from column in .csv

Tags: excel, powershell, csv

I need to get the highest number in column A,  by unique groups in Column B.

```
In the example .csv file above, there are 5 unique groups.
```

[CSV FILE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HX8yc.png)

I have the unique groups but I am stuck on how to get the highest number of each group.

```
 $dg = "file.csv"
 $lic = Import-Csv $dg
 $lic = $lic | Sort Name
 $lic | Select Name -Unique
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: please post the 1st few lines of your CSV - with at least 2 of the groups - and what you want from those lines.

Comment: Yes sorry, I am editing it...

Comment: I added an image of the file

Comment: PLEASE do not post pictures of code/data/errors. **_why? do you REALLY expect those who want to help you to type in what you already have as text?_** [*frown*]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `Group-Object` cmdlet to group the entries by Name, then sort each group based on Count:

```
Import-Csv file.csv |Group-Object Name |ForEach-Object {
    $_.Group |Sort {$_.Count -as [int]} |Select-Object -Last 1
}
```

Comment: Wow that simple, I looked at it too long or something.  This should have been easy.